# Adding FilterID to S3 cloudwatch alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a S3 bucket for which I enabled Request metrics.
I need to create an Cloudwatch alarm to monitor the metric 4XXErrors for S3.
I created the alarm manually and it was able to enter into alarm state for 4XXErrors.
But I need to create same alarm from terraform, so I am creating alarm using -

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm"

But what I am not able to find is the way to add **FilterId** which is created for S3.
I don't see any arguments being supported for FilterId.
While creating manually I can see that option.
Can someone please let me know is there any way we can add S3 metric FilterId in alarm created by Terraform ?

Comment: I believe it's going to be one of the `dimensions` values.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB 
It helped. I just added FilterId under dimensions and it worked

Comment: Nice. I think it would be worth posting an answer that shows your Terraform code.